# How much compound index is slower than single index

Tags: database, database-indexes

I'm thinking about removing index (A) and create compound index (A,B), because A and B are often use together in where clause.

However I wonder how will it impact query if only A will be requested in where clause.

Do you know how could it behave on different databases?

(index is created using default type on for example 10million record tables)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find out is to actually do it :)

So I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (ID INT,
FirstName VARCHAR(50),
LastName VARCHAR(50),
City VARCHAR(50))
```

Then inserted 100 xxx rows:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (ID,FirstName,LastName,City)
SELECT TOP 100000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.name) RowID,
'Bob1',
CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.name)%2 = 1 THEN 'Smith2'
ELSE 'Brown3' END,
CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.name)%10 = 1 THEN 'New York4'
WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.name)%10 = 5 THEN 'San Marino5'
WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.name)%10 = 3 THEN 'Los Angeles6'
ELSE 'Houston7' END
FROM sys.all_objects a
CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b
```

**then I've created two separate indexes:**

```
CREATE INDEX IX_FirstName ON TestTable(FirstName)
GO
CREATE INDEX IX_LastName ON TestTable(LastName)
GO
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT FirstName,
     LastName,       
     COUNT(*) RowsCount
FROM dbo.TestTable
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, City
```

Execution plan with two separate indexes:
[image]

**One composite index:**

```
CREATE INDEX IX_FirstName_LastName
ON TestTable(FirstName, LastName)
GO
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT FirstName,
     LastName,       
     COUNT(*) RowsCount
FROM dbo.TestTable
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, City
```

Execution plan with one composite index:
[image]

**Conclusion:**

It really depends on many factors such as database management system, version of database management system. However, it can be seen that there is no difference between two separate indexes and one compound index.

Pay attention, if you would like to use compound index then you should use **all** columns of a compound index in your query.